# Ridge regression within a loop

Tags: r, statistics, statsmodels

I am new in coding, so I still struggle with simple things as loops, subsetting, and data frame vs. matrix.

I am trying to fit a ridge regression for a multivariable X (X1=Marker 1, X2= Marker, X3= Marker 3,..., X1333= Marker 1333), shown in the first image, as a predictor variable of Y, in the second image.

[image]

[image]

**I want to compute the sum of the squared errors (SSE) for varying tuning parameter λ (between 1 and 20). My code is the following:**

```
#install.packages("MASS")
library(MASS)


fitridge <- function(x,y){
  fridge=lm.ridge (y ~ x, lambda = seq(0, 20, 2)) #Fitting a ridge regression for varying λ values
  sum(residuals(fridge)^2) #This results in SSE
}

all_gcv= apply(as.matrix(genmark_new),2,fitridge,y=as.matrix(coleslev_new)) 
}
```

However, it returns this error, and I don't know what to do anymore. I have tried converting the data set into a matrix, a data frame, changing the order of rows and columns...

```
Error in colMeans(X[, -Inter]) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions.
```

**I just would like to take each marker value from a single row (first picture), pass them into my fitridge function that fits a ridge regression against the Y from the second data set (in the second picture). 
And then subset the SSE and their corresponding lambda values**

Comment: you need to provide a formula for ridge.. before I write something.. are you sure this is what you want to do? you are ridge regression with 1 variable which makes no sense at all

Comment: http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/37-model-selection-essentials-in-r/153-penalized-regression-essentials-ridge-lasso-elastic-net/, you use ridge, lasso etc when you have many variables and want to penalize them. You have only one in this case????

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Yes, so the many variables would be each gene marker from the "genmark_new" data set (1st image) as predictors of each row in "coleslev_new" data set (2nd image). For example, take every column from the row F_1 in "genmark_new" as predictors of  the row F_1 in "coleslev_new"

Comment: hi @ValentinaGrilloAlvarado, ok yes, so you have cholesterol as a phenotype or response, and you want to find the marker most correlated with it. If you use ridge, you fit everything at one go. If you want to do it one variable at a time, you use a simple linear model.

Comment: my point is lambda only makes sense when you have a lot of independent variables. not when you have only 1

Comment: That's correct @StupidWolf I am trying to use ridge, but it doesn't let me loop row by row for gene markers as a response for cholesterol. I want to fit  F_1 from the gene marker data set with F_1 from cholesterol data set. And then repeat for row 2, 3, and so on and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fit a ridge with only one independent variable. It is not meant for this. In your case, most likely you have to do:

```
genmark_new = data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1,1333*100,replace=TRUE),ncol=1333))
colnames(genmark_new) = paste0("Marker_",1:ncol(genmark_new))
coleslev_new = data.frame(NormalizedCholesterol=rnorm(100))
Y = coleslev_new$NormalizedCholesterol

library(MASS)
fit = lm.ridge (y ~ ., data=data.frame(genmark_new,y=Y),lambda = seq(0, 20, 2))
```

And calculate residuals for each lambda:

```
apply(fit$coef,2,function(i)sum((Y-as.matrix(genmark_new) %*% i)^2))
       0        2        4        6        8       10       12       14 
26.41866 27.88029 27.96360 28.04675 28.12975 28.21260 28.29530 28.37785 
      16       18       20 
28.46025 28.54250 28.62459
```

If you need to fit each variable separately, you can consider using a linear model:

```
fitlm <- function(x,y){
  fridge=lm(y ~ x) 
  sum(residuals(fridge)^2)
}

all_gcv= apply(genmark_new,2,fitlm,y=Y)
```

Suggestion, check out [make notes or introductions to ridge](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Ridge_Regression.pdf), they are meant for multiple variate regressions, that is, more than 1 independent variable.